# Liability for data when reselling used data storage (US)

Tags: data-protection, data-storage

If I purchase used storage media from a company, what is my liability for the data that it may contain?

As a standard practice, all such media would be wiped. However, secure data destruction is not my business.

From an ethical standpoint, I would want make a "best effort" to ensure that all data is removed. However, from a legal perspective, where does the liability reside in the event of data being leaked?

Is there a "standard" disclaimer of liability for situations such as this that I can use, or is this a case "there be dragons, contact a lawyer"?

Comment: What does the sales agreement from the company say about the storage media and any existing data? That will be a contract that outlines liability.

Comment: If it contains data from anybody who is in the EU, then the EU's GDPR will probably be relevant.

Comment: @phoog would it? I can become legally responsible for data I didn’t collect if I happen to find it on a lost flash drive?

Comment: @DaleM the GDPR might be relevant without creating a legal responsibility on the part of the person finding the data.  Perhaps the storage device is evidence of a breach of the GDPR.  The purpose for which the found data are used might or might not be within the scope of the GDPR.  But yes, I think it's generally true that if you find data on a lost flash drive you can become legally responsible for it, even if that won't necessarily be true in all circumstances.

Comment: What country are you in?  Data privacy rights vary a lot between the US and most of Europe.

Comment: @DavidThornley I'm in the US.